# Problem with writing rotated image as a jpeg file

Tags: c, image, image-processing, stb-image

In the main part, I rotated the image. Then I wrote a code for writing my image to in project file as a jpeg file. I couldn't do it.

Here is my code:

They are some definitions and libraries I used. (I also added standard libraries.)

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image_write.h"

#define CHANNEL_NUM 3



int main() {
     .
     .
     .
     write(&out_image); // calling by reference

}
```

After this part, I want to write my image as a jpg file. So this is the writing part:

```
int write(unsigned char *rgb_image)
 {
    
    int width =400; 
    int height = 400;
    
    rgb_image = malloc(width*height*CHANNEL_NUM);       
    stbi_write_jpg("rotated_image", width, height, CHANNEL_NUM, rgb_image, width*CHANNEL_NUM);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure about the second part so I share it with you. By the way, I don't get any errors in both functions. (main and write)

**If you want the full code, let me know in the comment section. I can share my main function too.**

Comment: We don't want full code, but we want a [mre]

Comment: The last parameter to stbi_write_jpg() is quality, an int from 1 to 100% quality (=compression).  Anything over 100 is set to 100.  You allocate rgb_image right before writing it, and that memory isn't initialized to anything.  Is that what you meant to do?